Force Listbox Item Unselected
My Index sheet's Listbox3 has an item highlighted blue/selected permanently. It has it at workbook open after the code fills the listbox. I have tried many methods in this forum, but nothing seems to work. Listbox2 has this same code, but it doesn't leave the clicked item selected for some reason. I copied LB2 and pasted it as LB3, thinking maybe its a property issue, but that didn't resolve the issue. Any Ideas to try?
        Private Sub ListBox3_Click()
    
         Sheets(ListBox3.Text).Visible = True
         Sheets(ListBox3.Text).Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Index")
         Sheets(ListBox3.Text).Activate
         'Me.ListBox3.ListIndex = -1
         'Sheets("Index").ListBox3.ListIndex = -1
         'Sheets(ListBox3.Text).listItem.Selected = False    
          
    End Sub


This was missing in the Index Sheet activation module. I don't know why the item was selected upon workbook activation though, because it was there.
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Index").ListBox3
            .Clear
            .List = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("K1:K12").Value
        End With

